# Python Error Launching Native Debug Session in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++

I have created an Android Project with C++ support with empty MainActivity.
Before making any changes I try to run it and get this error:

> Connecting to com.ewa.myapplication Now Launching Native Debug Session
>   File "C:\Python3\Lib\site.py", line 177
>       file=sys.stderr)
>           ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Why is this error happening?

Win10 dev environment
Android Studio 3.0.1
PYTHONPATH =  C:\Python3;C:\Python3\Lib;C:\Python3\DLLs;C:\Python3\Lib\lib-tk

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run without the PYTHONPATH environment variable? If you attach a phone your device maybe see if you can push an apk onto it. Or use a emulator. If that works then try again and include PYTHONPATH